# C# Serialization Remove attribute name from result

Tags: c#, xml, xml-serialization, removeclass

I'm not able to remove the name of the Attribute **Values** in **clsProduct** from my xml. I tried using `[XmlElement(ElementName = "Values", Type = typeof(clsValues)]` for my `List<clsValues>` but it didn't give me the result I need.

You can see the result I need below.

Parts of my serialization class:

```
[Serializable]
public class clsProduct
{
    [XmlAttribute("ID")]
    public string ID { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("UserTypeID")]
    public string UserTypeID { get; set; }

    [XmlArrayItem(ElementName = "Values", Type = typeof(clsValues))]
    public List<clsValues> Values { get; set; }

}

[Serializable]
public class clsValues
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Value")]
    public clsValue Value { get; set; }

    [XmlArray(ElementName = "MultiValue"),
    XmlArrayItem(ElementName = "Value")]
    public List<clsValue> MultiValue { get; set; }
}

[Serializable]
public class clsValue
{
    [XmlAttribute("AttributeID")]
    public string AttributeID { get; set; }

    [XmlText]
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

My current xml result:

```
<Product ID="PROD-01111010" UserTypeID="Product">
   <Values>
     <Values>
        <Value AttributeID="ATTR-7196">201607280755</Value>
     </Values>
     <Values>
        <Value AttributeID="ATTR-6236">PTFE 125 + 25% GF, Platte</Value>
     </Values>
     <Values>
        <MultiValue>
            <Value>PLATTE</Value>
            <Value>LUBRIFLON 225</Value>
            <Value>PLAQUE</Value>
            <Value>LUBRIFLON 22</Value>
        </MultiValue>
     </Values>
  </Values>
</Product>
```

Result I need:

```
<Product ID="PROD-01111010" UserTypeID="Product">
  <Values>
     <Value AttributeID="ATTR-7196">201607280755</Value>
     <Value AttributeID="ATTR-6236">PTFE 125 + 25% GF, Platte</Value>
     <MultiValue>
        <Value>PLATTE</Value>
        <Value>LUBRIFLON 225</Value>
        <Value>PLAQUE</Value>
        <Value>LUBRIFLON 22</Value>
     </MultiValue>
   </Values>
 </Product>
```

Can someone help?

Thanks

Edit: 
When I'm using

`[XmlElement(ElementName = "Values", Type = typeof(clsValues))]
 public List<clsValues> Values { get; set; }`

instead of `XmlArrayItem` I get this result:

```
<Product ID="PROD-01111010" UserTypeID="Product">
     <Values>
        <Value AttributeID="ATTR-7196">201607280755</Value>
     </Values>
     <Values>
        <Value AttributeID="ATTR-6236">PTFE 125 + 25% GF, Platte</Value>
     </Values>
     <Values>
        <MultiValue>
            <Value>PLATTE</Value>
            <Value>LUBRIFLON 225</Value>
            <Value>PLAQUE</Value>
            <Value>LUBRIFLON 22</Value>
        </MultiValue>
     </Values>
</Product>
```

Comment: As a side note, now would be a very good time to stop using the `cls` prefix and start following normal .NET naming conventions.

Comment: @JonSkeet I normally don't use prefixes. I didn't create the project I'm extending it and don't want to have two naming conventions in one application.

Comment: Well I'd suggest to your co-workers that they start following the naming conventions then - and don't forget that you're posting a Stack Overflow question; it doesn't have to be the exact code, so long as it shows the same exact problem. That means you can make it simpler and more conventional, to provide fewer distractions for readers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue relates to this property:

```
[XmlArrayItem(ElementName = "Values", Type = typeof(clsValues))]
public List<clsValues> Values { get; set; }
```

The implication is there are *multiple* elements called `Values` that have a specific type `clsValues`. And each of these have one or both of `Value` or `MultiValue` children.

What you want is the *array* to be an element `Values` and for the *array items* to be a choice between your two different element types - it either contains a `Value` element or a `MultiValue` element.

You can structure like this to achieve that:

```
public class Product
{
    [XmlAttribute("ID")]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("UserTypeID")]
    public string UserTypeId { get; set; }

    [XmlArray("Values")]
    [XmlArrayItem("Value", typeof(Value))]
    [XmlArrayItem("MultiValue", typeof(MultiValue))]
    public List<object> Values { get; set; }
}

public class MultiValue
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Value")]
    public List<Value> Values { get; set; }
}

public class Value
{
    [XmlAttribute("AttributeID")]
    public string AttributeId { get; set; }

    [XmlText]
    public string Text { get; set; }
}
```

See [this fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/FCABnV) for a working demo.

Answer (score 1):

May be you should use

```
[XmlElement(ElementName = "Values", Type = typeof(clsValues))]
public List<clsValues> Values { get; set; }
```

Instead of

```
[XmlArrayItem(ElementName = "Values", Type = typeof(clsValues))]
```

Comment: When I implement that the first and last <Values> disappears.

Answer (score 0):

Try xml linq

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);

            XElement values = doc.Descendants("Values").FirstOrDefault();
            List<XElement> elements = values.Elements().ToList();
            for (int index = elements.Count() - 1; index >= 0; index--)
            {
                elements[index].ReplaceWith(elements[index].Elements());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Reason, why it is serializating like that, is because XML is using second `<Values></Values>` as delimeter. It is needed because your `clsValues` object can has `Value` and `MultiValue` property set at the same time. In that case XML in your needed format

```
<Product ID="PROD-01111010" UserTypeID="Product">
  <Values>
     <Value AttributeID="ATTR-7196">201607280755</Value>
     <Value AttributeID="ATTR-6236">PTFE 125 + 25% GF, Platte</Value>
     <MultiValue>
        <Value>PLATTE</Value>
        <Value>LUBRIFLON 225</Value>
        <Value>PLAQUE</Value>
        <Value>LUBRIFLON 22</Value>
     </MultiValue>
   </Values>
 </Product>
```

could be backward interpreted as 1 object with `Value` set and 1 object with both `Value` and `MultiValue` set which is wrong, or as 1 object with `Value` set, 1 object with `Value` set and 1 object with `MultiValue` set which is correct. But XML parser can't know, which interpretation is correct. If you surrely know, that your object will always has only 1 property set, you can write your own Serializator and Deserializator with implemented one property rule.

Comment: So far as I understand your post, the serializer is not able to serialize an xml in my needed format?